# Montar Django en cyberpanel

Tags: nodejs, django, hosting, openlitespeed

Hola lo que pasa es que ando realizando un proyecto y contrate un vps con hostinger que tenia ubuntu 22.04 con cyberpanel incluido lo que pase que cuando sigo los tutoriales
por ejemplo este
https://community.cyberpanel.net/t/how-to-setup-django-application-on-cyberpanel-openlitespeed/30646

en el paso 2 osea este
curl -O http://www.litespeedtech.com/packages/lsapi/wsgi-lsapi-1.7.tgz
tar xf wsgi-lsapi-1.7.tgz
cd wsgi-lsapi-1.7
python3 ./configure.py
make
cp lswsgi /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/

al momento de escribir make me arroja un error
[image: codigo error]

y bueno hostinger la ia me dijo que hiciera esto
[image: hostinger]

y lo puse pero igual da error

no entiendo que pasa, tutorial que veo tutorial que tiene ese famoso make pero es que a mi no funciona, necesito ayuda

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.